# How to install MySql on Red Hat 6.1?

Tags: linux, rhel, rpm, mysql

I am trying to install `MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686.rpm` on a Red Hat Enterprise 6.1 server.

I receive the following error:

```
rpm -Uvh MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
        libaio.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libaio.so.1(LIBAIO_0.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.1.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.10) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.8) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libcrypt.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libcrypt.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libdl.so.2 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libgcc_s.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libgcc_s.so.1(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libm.so.6 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libpthread.so.0 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.0) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.1) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        librt.so.1 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libstdc++.so.6 is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
        libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.11) is needed by MySQL-server-5.6.12-1.el6.i686
```

I recognize that these are programs I need to install. My question is where should I look to download these programs to install or should I just look for an older version of MySQL?

**EDIT**: In the end it was actually a system architecture problem.  System architecture should always be kept in mind when installing components in linux.  I was using a i686 rpm when it was a x86_x64 system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YUM rep which updated version of MySQL, as in here:http://www.webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/

Answer (score 1):

It's highly recommended to use the packages that come with your distribution. RHEL 6.1 comes with 5.1.52, and you should use that.

Actually  - you should think about updating the machine to a later level.

Comment: If you sill want the latest version, use YUM repository with latest version, as in here: http://www.webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/